# Issue while moving textfield up and down on tap of text field

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

I have placed a toolbar with a button above my keyboard to dismiss it. I am having a problem while moving the textview up and down. If the textview is covered by keyboard scroll rect works fine. Sometimes the textview is not covered by keyboard but the toolbar covers it. I want the textview to move up also in this case and it should move above my toolbar on tap of textview. Currently my textview is not moving up when it is covered by toolbar. How to achieve this?

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scroll scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

//To add toolbar above textview
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 30)];
            numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
            numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:AGLocalizedString(@"key_done",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(returnKeyboardOnDone)],
                                   nil];
            [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
            subTitleTxtFld.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
            compaintSummaryTxt.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
            aeTxtView.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the reference variable of your toolbar, In place of keyboard size height, Keep (keyboard size height + toolbar height). That will do the work.

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height + toolBar.frame.size.height, 0.0);
```

Comment: And accordingly you have to handle cases if there are multiple UITextFields and UITextViews, some of them with Toolbar above keyboard and some only keyboard without ToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a rect and scrolling it, scroll the caretRect.

```
CGRect caretRect = [self.textView caretRectForPosition:self.textView.selectedTextRange.end];
// add some extra space to scroll
caretRect.size.height += 7;
[self.textView scrollRectToVisible:caretRect animated:YES];
```